# ¿Como transformar una imagen que obtuve de un input a base 64 con php?

Tags: php, html, imagen, base64

Me gustaría transformar una imagen a base64 obtenida de un input. Pero al hacerlo me imprime "ZGVzY2FyZ2ExLmpwZw==" o algo parecido con cada imagen que pruebo. ¿Como le hago para que realmente me salga la imagen en base 64?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form role="form" action="imagen.php" method="post" name="productoform">
        <input type="file" name="imagen" required class="form-control">
        <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Base64">
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$imagen = utf8_decode($_POST['imagen']);
$imdata = base64_encode($imagen);

echo $imdata;
?>
```

Comment: Tiene pinta de que lo estás haciendo a la inversa. Estás decodificando la imagen que te llega por post, en vez de codificarla, y luego estás codificando eso en base 64, haciéndole después el **echo**.

Comment: Gracias por comentar, pero creo que no, ya que para decodificar se utiliza "base64_decode" y yo uso"base64_encode"

Comment: Perdón, había leído mal tu código. Lo que estás haciendo es codificar la imagen en base 64 con **base64_encode()**. Lo que te muestra el **echo** es precisamente eso, el chorro de caracteres que es la codificación en base 64.

Comment: Si exacto eso deberia hacer, pero no me muestra el "chorro" de caracteres solo me muestra algunos, cuando deberia mostrarme todos

Comment: El uso habitual es: Codificas la imagen que te llega por post y almacenas ese chorro de caracteres en la base de datos. Luego cuando quieras mostrarla de nuevo tienes que hacerle un **base64_decode()**.

Comment: si lo entiendo pero primero quiero verificar si si lo está haciendo bien, y si lo imprime mal lo ingresará mal a la BD

Comment: Una imagen codificada tiene una extensión bastante grande de caracteres. Si la cadena que recibes es tan corta podrías verificar si **$_POST['imagen']** tiene efectivamente la imagen o en cambio estás codificando lo que no es.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86543/discussion-between-phpmyguel-and-samuel-viema).